# Alexa Discovery Skill - Return Connected Devices

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

I am working on a Smart Home Alexa Skill and corresponding Lambda function. There are many demos and they all seem to return canned text. Is there a way through Lambda/JS to get a list of connected devices for a users account?

Samples like this:

```
const USER_DEVICES = [
{
    // This id needs to be unique across all devices discovered for a given manufacturer
    applianceId: 'unique-id-for-non-dimmable-bulb-specific-to-user1',
 },{},{},...]
```

I would love to implement code that was more like this:

```
const USER_DEVICES = Some.Alexa.Function.GetConnectedDevices()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out the smart home skill API yet? It'll let you interact with connected devices and get data back about them: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smarthome/understand-the-smart-home-skill-api.html

Comment: I think this API is intended for skills that provide their own devices. The discovery is a request from Alexa to your skill, not the other way around. I wish there was a way for a Skill to discover other connected devices.